# How to change the highlighting color in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, javafx

How to change the highlighting color in JavaFX? Usually it is blue with gradients, but I would like to have a green highlighting. I have tried the following:

```
.root{
    -fx-shadow-highlight-color: #CCFF99;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at **caspian.css** (JavaFX 2) or **modena.css** (JavaFX 8)

```
.root {
    /* A bright blue for highlighting/accenting objects.  For example: selected
     * text; selected items in menus, lists, trees, and tables; progress bars;
     * default buttons.
     */
    -fx-accent: #0093ff;

    /* A bright blue for the focus indicator of objects. Typically used as the
     * first color in -fx-background-color for the "focused" pseudo-class. Also
     * typically used with insets of -1.4 to provide a glowing effect.
     *
     * TODO: should this be derived from -fx-accent?
     */
    -fx-focus-color: #0093ff;
}
```

Change these colors according to their usages.

Comment: Thanks very much! And should i change the hover-background of ListViews manually ? Or is there a way to change them global like -fx-accent?

Comment: ListView hover color is: `-fx-cell-hover-color` - it too can be found in [caspian.css - here is a link to the 2.2 version](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css)

Answer (score 2):

I think Uluk Biy has answered it great way.

But the reality is styling using CSS does not override the -fx-focus-color: #0093ff, rather it will overlap. If you use -fx-focus-color: red , it will get mixed with default blue color and show a shade of grey like color. The css attribute -fx-accent has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `-fx-highlight-fill` on `text-area` class selector.

```
.text-area {
    -fx-highlight-fill: green;
}
```