# JavaFX - Change CSS specific values in runtime

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am doing a JavaFX application using a base css file.

I would like to have a feature where the user can select a base color, maybe using a Color Picker or something like that and I will change the css file to calculate the colors using this as base.

Or maybe a custom way to use derive method inside the CSS file using variables instead of static colors?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the predefined colors of JavaFX from modena.css (or caspian.css for older JavaFX-2). For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14126606). These colors are base for the most controls of JavaFX, but there are of course more specific colors defined for some controls only.

You can change them on runtime, and apply to top level (or any) pane, i.e. parent root of scene:

```
Color selectedColor = colorPicker.getValue();

String rgb = getRgbString( selectedColor );
myScene.getRoot().setStyle( "-fx-accent: " + rgb + "; -fx-focus-color:" + rgb );
```

where

```
private String getRgbString( Color color )
{
    int r = ( int ) Math.round( color.getRed() * 255.0 );
    int g = ( int ) Math.round( color.getGreen() * 255.0 );
    int b = ( int ) Math.round( color.getBlue() * 255.0 );

    return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}
```

You may also make the [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) more brighter, darker and/or derive new color from it. Refer to api.